# SQL Date between today and 7 days after

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a view where I need to select all the elements where the date is between today and + 7 days.

I have for example:

2018-11-30
   2018-06-30
2018-10-31
  2018-05-31
   2018-04-16
  2018-04-12
  2018-04-02

From this list I need only these two elements:

2018-04-16

2018-04-12

I have tried already like this:

```
 WHERE sl.GettingBackDate > CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) as DATE)
```

but this returns all the elements where the date is greater than today

```
WHERE sl.GettingBackDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

this don't return any element

I created an SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27d5c/2

Can you advise?

Comment: Try other way around.. `WHERE GettingBackDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1 ,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this double filter.

```
WHERE 
    sl.GettingBackDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND -- From today onwards
    sl.GettingBackDate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 8) -- Less than 8 days from now (strict)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following where condition

```
WHERE 
    sl.GettingBackDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND 
    sl.GettingBackDate <= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE()))
```